# R - Select string text between two values

Tags: r

I have a string stored in R.  What code can I use to extract the text between two values?  For example:

```
sql <- "SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM tbl WHERE x=y"
```

I want to extract `field1, field2, field3` as a separate string.  I can use `substring` but I'm not clear on how to determine the integer values relating to the end of "SELECT " and the start of " FROM".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one option using `gsub`:

```
gsub("^.*SELECT *(.*?) +FROM.*$", "\\1", sql)
```

Comment: Nice! I am still learning about regular expressions. However, this leaves an white space at the end of the string..

Comment: I think you should rather do: `gsub("^.*SELECT *(.*) * FROM.*$", "\\1", sql)`. **Note the space before `FROM`**.

Comment: @Mariam, I changed the " *" to " +" which means that that part must match at least 1 space (since it seems unlikely that there would not still be at least one space before "FROM".  However, due to greediness if there are 2 or more spaces before "FROM" all but one of them will still be in the result.  Changing "(.*)" to "(.*?)" removes the greediness and will not capture the space after the last field.

Comment: Greg, just for curiosity's sake, how would I modify your string to remove all of the text between SELECT and FROM instead of the text outside it?  That would help me understand exactly what the characters are doing in the regular expression.  Thanks!!

Comment: @JeffreyKramer, There are several options, here is one: `gsub("SELECT.*FROM","SELECTFROM", sql)`.  Actually if there is only 1 instance of "SELECT" and "FROM" then you could use `sub` instead of `gsub`.  See `?regex` in R for details on regular expressions and the great book by Friedl, there are also many tutorials on the web.

Comment: @GregSnow Thanks for the explanation! +1 for both answer and comment.

Comment: Thanks, this is a huge help.  Right now the SQL expression is really simple but I can see where there could be lots of complications later on for more complicated strings.  This is really great stuff, I've learned a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
 split_sql = strsplit(sql, split = " ")
 result = paste(split_sql[1][[2]], split_sql[1][[3]], split_sql[1][[4]], sep = " ")
```

This will give you:

```
 #[1] "field1, field2, field3"
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't totally accurate.  It's just a character string, not a true SQL object.

Comment: Got it. Please check my updated answer. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

My preference would be:

```
# Pull out strings between SELECT and FROM
Fields = gsub("SELECT (.*) FROM.*","\\1",sql)
# Remove spaces
CleanFields = (gsub("\\s+", "", Fields))
# Split into items
Items = unlist(strsplit(CleanFields,","))
```

Then you can index each field1 as Items[1]

(Of course this could be put into a function or combined to one line...)

Answer (score 0):

1) One approach is to delete everything not wanted:

```
gsub("^SELECT *| FROM .*", "", sql)
```

2) Another approach if we had a data frame with the required fields is to run the query using sqldf and then take its names:

```
library(sqldf)
tbl <- data.frame(field1 = 1, field2 = 2, field3 = 3, x = 4, y = 5)
toString(names(sqldf(sql)))
```